# Buying a Linux Machine

Tags: hardware

As a budding dev, I'm looking to buy a linux machine to work with. What are my options in buying a machine that comes installed with linux?

EDIT: I guess my question really was, is there such a thing as buying a machine with linux pre-installed because there doesn't seem to be many options available.

Anyway, I found [this](http://www.berkeleylug.com/?p=168) link helpful.

Comment: to be honest, building a machine isnt very difficult and it'll save you money usually. Besides, as a dev you'll likely have pretty specific requirements. I'd say just build it yourself from the various parts. Should take about 45 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:
[Ubuntu certification](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification)